# How to call atomic member function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers, atomic

I'm having an issue calling a member function pointer that is atomic:

```
class test
{
   typedef void(test::*ProcessPtr)();
   std::atomic<ProcessPtr> _processPtr;  
   void process() {}
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    test t;
    t._processPtr = &test::process;
    (t.*_processPtr)();  
}
```

The error is:

t.cpp:238:6: error: ‘_processPtr’ was not declared in this scope
  (t.*_processPtr)();

Not quite sure what the issue is.. Can you not deference an "atomic" member function pointer?

Comment: Try (t.*t._processPtr)();

Comment: Now I get:  error: ‘t.test::_processPtr’ cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type ‘std::atomic<void (test::*)()>’
  (t.*t._processPtr)();

Comment: There's the answer to your question. :-)

Comment: Something like `test::ProcessPtr pp = t._processPtr.load();` and `(t.*pp)();`?

Comment: It compiles but doesn't link for me with gcc4.8.3:   t.cpp:(.text.startup+0x63): undefined reference to `__atomic_store_16'
t.cpp:(.text.startup+0x70): undefined reference to `__atomic_load_16'

Comment: @SubliminalBroccoli Linking against `-latomic` should help here

Comment: @MikevanDyke I did link against atomic,but I don't think the size of a member function pointer is an issue.

Comment: @SubliminalBroccoli and you're using the code as specified in the question or are there any differences? Using the code above and linking against `-latomic` works for me. Which compiler are you using? Which standard library?

Answer (score 2):

As super pointed out you need to use the object twice:

```
(t.*t._processPtr.load())();
 ^  ^             ^----- load() because it's an atomic variable
 |  |---- this loads the function pointer stored inside of t
 |------- actual Object to call the member function pointer on
```

So you end up with this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    test t;
    t._processPtr = &test::process;
    (t.*t._processPtr.load())();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`_processPtr` is not availiable. make it `public` like so.

```
class test
{
public:
    typedef void(test::*ProcessPtr)();
    std::atomic<ProcessPtr> _processPtr;
    void process() {};
}
```

with `atomic` you use `.store()` and `.load()` to write and read. not sure how it works with pointers though.

Comment: it was public.. just forgot to type that out

Answer (score 0):

I found out why. this relates to the template argument deduction.

If you see the template class 'atomic', have a class of primary T and class specialize with T *. then I compare the pointer to function and pointer to function member. `code` can be seen below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct A
{ 
    static void Call(){std::cout << "Call T" << std::endl;}
};
template<typename T>
struct A<T*>
{ 
    static void Call(){std::cout << "Call T*" << std::endl;}
};

struct B {};

int main()
{
    A<void(B::*)()>::Call();
    A<void(*)()>::Call();
}
```

output:

```
Call T
Call T*
```

Suggest improvement, use a double pointer to function member:

update in class test, from `std::atomic<ProcessPtr> _processPtr;` to `std::atomic<ProcessPtr*> _processPtr;`

and update in main function:

```
int main()
{
    test t;
    test::ProcessPtr d = &test::process;
    t._processPtr = &d;
    (t.*(*(t._processPtr)))();  
}
```

Comment: yes that would work, though another level of indirection